# Cannot remove IntelliSense extension in VSC

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I installed IntelliSense for Python. I uninstalled it but it steel seems to be installed. This is my structure of files:

```
websockets/
├── trades_btc_eur.py
└── functions
    ├── GracefulKiller.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── Logging.py
    └── Websockets.py
```

I import some functions from `functions` package in trades_btc_eur.py:

```
from functions.Logging import create_logger
from functions.GracefulKiller import GracefulKiller
from functions.Websockets import ImprovedWebsocketClient
```

And I can see this errors in `PROBLEMS`:

```
Unable to resolve 'functions.Logging'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module.
Unable to resolve 'functions.GracefulKiller'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module.
Unable to resolve 'functions.Websockets'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module.
```

And all three lines are underlined. I tried restart VSC and PC, add `__init__.py` to websockets directory, upgrade to latest version of VSC. Nothing helped. I do not see it in my installed extensions. Program works fine, could anybody explain me, how to get rid of `IntelliSense`?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliSense is part of the Python extension for VS Code, so you would have to install that extension to install IntelliSense.

But if you add `"python.analysis.disabled": ["unresolved-import"]` to your settings then that will turn off the warning.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it works, but what I see, VSC cannot find my functions package. Thats why analysis generate this problems. The program works well, so I would like to know why VSC cannot find package function and moduls Logging, GracefulKiller or Websockets? Did I make some mistake I cannot find right now?

Comment: If your `websockets` directory is a subdirectory of your workspace then that would explain this. If you opened `websockets` as the folder in VS Code then it should work.

Comment: thank you, it works. My `websockets` directory is subdirectory. Why it is not work? I have __init__.py in my functions directory, which is in the same directory as my trades_btc_eur.py. So I do not understand what exactly is the problem. Why it is work when I start it, but unable to resolve it?

Comment: Because the extension resolves from the top of your workspace, so to the extension you have `websockets.functions`, not `functions` as a package. The other way to fix this is to set your `PYTHONPATH` in a e.g. `.env` file so that your `websockets` directory gets added.